# PHP code stop being interpreted from ">" character

Tags: php

I just migrated all files of Wordpress in another server (shared).
I imported the database and changed old domain name.

When I go to the wp-login page, it displays the PHP code instead of the login form interface :

```
` element. * Default 'Log In'. 
* @param string $message Optional. Message to display in header. Default empty. 
* @param WP_Error $wp_error Optional. The error to pass. Default is a WP_Error instance. 
*/ function login_header( $title = 'Log In', $message = '', $wp_error = null ) { 
global $error, $interim_login, $action; // Don't index any of these forms. add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wp_robots_sensitive_page' )
...
```

If I look at the php code, I realize that the PHP stop being interpreted from this character.
So I checked the PHP version, which is 7.3.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtwZM.png

Have you any idea why it does not display the login form ?
I ran it without any problem in local (with the same PHP version).

Thanks

Comment: what does server php error log say?

Comment: @eugeneKapustin The only thing in log is : 

"[Sun May 08 20:38:50 2022] [error] [client ************] [host www.***********.be] AH01264: script not found or unable to stat: /homez.583/***********/www/wp-cron.php, referer: http://www.***********.be/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1652035130.5803151130676269531250"

Comment: try to set at the very beginning of your script this:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
so set it right after <?php
and see whether you see error reported when you try to enter the page with browser

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found the error.
I commented these lines in my .htaccess :

```
    #<IfModule mime_module>
        #  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
    #</IfModule>
```

But I do not know what is their purpose...

Comment: Please do research in order for you to know what this line do and then update the answer. https://wiki.crowncloud.net/?How_to_change_the_PHP_version_of_subdomain_in_cPanel#Available+PHP+Handlers.